# module config ViewJsonStrategy settings didn't work under child_route link

Tags: php, json, module, zend-framework2

I don't know how can I explain my problem. I'm trying to get JSON response from one of my module that extend abstractrestfulcontroler. I have following module configuration

File: module.config.php

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                    'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwCommunication' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwCommunicationController',
                    'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwChat' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwChatController',
                    'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwContacts' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwContactsController',
                    'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwMessage' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwMessageController',
                    'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwUserMessageTemplates' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwUserMessageTemplatesController',
                    'TfwCommunicationControllerTfwUserMessageTemplates' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwUserMessageTemplatesController',
            ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                    'communication' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/communication',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                            #'id' => '[0-9]+', # '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        #'action'=>'[a-z][a-z0-9]*',
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwCommunication',
                                            'action' => 'index',
                                            #'id'=>'update',
                                            #'action'     => 'index',
                                    ),
                            ),
                            'may_terminate' => true,
                            'child_routes' => array(
                                    'actions'=>array(
                                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                                            'options' => array(
                                                    'route'    => '/[:action[/]]',
                                                    'constraints' => array(
                                                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                    ),
                                                    'defaults' => array(
                                                            'controller' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwCommunication',
                                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                    'message' => array(
                                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                                            'options' => array(
                                                    'route'    => '/message',
                                                    'defaults' => array(
                                                            'controller' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwMessage',
                                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                                        ),
                                                ),
                                            'may_terminate' => true,
                                            'child_routes' => array(
                                                    'read'=>array(
                                                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                                                            'options' => array(
                                                                    'route'    => '/[:id]',
                                                                    'constraints' => array(
                                                                            'id' => '[0-9]*',
                                                                        ),
                                                                    'defaults' => array(
                                                                            'controller' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwMessage',
                                                                            'action'     => 'read',
                                                                        ),
                                                                ),
                                                        ),
                                                    'actions'=>array(
                                                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                                                            'options' => array(
                                                                    'route'    => '/[:action[/[:id]]]',
                                                                    'constraints' => array(
                                                                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                                            'id' => '.*',
                                                                        ),
                                                                    'defaults' => array(
                                                                            'controller' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwMessage',
                                                                            'action'     => 'index',
                                                                        ),
                                                                ),
                                                        ),
                                                    'json-request-by-child-route'=>array(
                                                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                                                            'options' => array(
                                                                    'route'    => '/json-request-by-child-route[/:id]',
                                                                    'constraints' => array(
                                                                            'id' => '.*',
                                                                        ),
                                                                    'defaults' => array(
                                                                            'controller' => 'TfwCommunicationControllerTfwUserMessageTemplates',
                                                                        ),
                                                                ),
                                                            ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    'user-defined-templates'=>array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/communication/message/user-defined-templates[/:id]',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                            'id' => '.*',
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwUserMessageTemplates',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    'user-defined-templates-direct-link'=>array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/user-defined-templates-direct-link[/:id]',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                            'id' => '.*',
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'TfwCommunication\\Controller\\TfwUserMessageTemplates',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                    'tfwcommunication' => __DIR__ . DS.'..'.DS.'view',
            ),
            'strategies' => array(
                    'ViewJsonStrategy',
            ),
    ),
```

);

Now following link is working - tfw.com.bd/communication/message/user-defined-templates/ OR tfw.com.bd/user-defined-templates-direct-link/

But following link will not work as expected (it says 404 controller not found) - tfw.com.bd/communication/message/json-request-by-child-route

Here tfw.com.bd indicating localhost.
Please note, I'm expected output as JSON format.
Also noted that, all I use here same controller. In some link/route it didn't work. I can't figure out the reason.

Can any ZF2 expert here who can explain the real reason behind the behavior.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *following link will not work as expected* ? Does it hit the controller method or not ?

Comment: it says 404 controller not found

Comment: You miss backslashes in that line

Comment: its not the issue, i create invokables with same name i.e. without backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got this answer by myself. The above routing configuration didn't works due to default "action" define as "index". Zend seek "action" parameter, if found then it load that action. If not found it return "notFoundAction". So, in child route of above router defines "action" parameter. So, Zend din't go further when either it goes default "indexAction" or goes "notFoundAction".

Footnote, you need to avoid action parameter to get "JsonStrategy" works as expected. If you can't avoid action parameter in your router you can fix it by overloading "onDispatch" method of "AbstractRestfulController" controller.

Here is my code that works for me -

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e){
    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
    if (! $routeMatch) {
        /**
         * @todo Determine requirements for when route match is missing.
         *       Potentially allow pulling directly from request metadata?
         */
        throw new Exception\DomainException(
                'Missing route matches; unsure how to retrieve action');
    }

    $request = $e->getRequest();

    // Was an "action" requested?
    #die('get_class($routeMatch): '.get_class($routeMatch).' @'.__LINE__.': '.__FILE__);
    $action  = $routeMatch->getParam('action', false);


    if ($action) {
        // Handle arbitrary methods, ending in Action
        $method = static::getMethodFromAction($action);
        if (! method_exists($this, $method)) {
            if($method=='indexAction'){
                $routeMatch->setParam('action', false);
                return parent::onDispatch($e);
            }
            $method = 'notFoundAction';
        }
        $return = $this->$method();
        $e->setResult($return);
        return $return;
    }
    return parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```